# Minimizing values of expressions dependent on more variables

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I need to enforce seven expressions dependent on seven variables to be zero. However, the expressions are quite complicated and generaly I get a system of transcendental equations which only sometimes has a real solution (I am using `NSolve` function).

In principle, I would be satisfied if I found such values of variables for which the expressions were close to zero. Is it possible? I was trying to utilize `NMinimize`, but I am not sure how to make it work for minimizing more expressions.

Comment: Have you tried `FindRoot`?

Comment: Its generally considered helpful to share your code attempts and equations, hopefully in a well [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help), so we can quickly see the problem you are facing. Please [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) accordingly if possible.